# R function to return the order of sorted elements in an unordered vector?

Tags: r

I would like to determine the indices of elements of an unsorted vector in order (e.g. lowest to highest)

#### Example

```
vec <- c(14, 50, 10, 41, 9)
return_indices(vec)
5 3 1 4 2
```

I suspect there'd be an easy way to achieve this, but I cannot think of how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably using `sort` and `match` :

```
match(sort(vec), vec)
#[1] 5 3 1 4 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `order` function

```
vec <- c(14, 50, 10, 41, 9)
order(vec)
```

```
> order(vec)
[1] 5 3 1 4 2
```

Comment: Interesting to note the difference in behaviour when there are duplicates in `vec`. I.e. `vec <- c(14, 50, 10, 14, 41, 9); order(vec)` returns `6 3 1 4 5 2`. Whereas @RonakShah's `match(sort(vec), vec)` solution returns `6 3 1 1 5 2`. Subtle differences depending on the use case

Comment: @stevec The difference will occur because `match` will return the first element it matches to. A common use case for me is to want to rearrange the values of y depending on how x is reordered by sorting. This is useful when plotting lines between a sequence of (x,y) pairs. The `order` solution would keep the right y, the `match` one would not.

Comment: I am using it for something similar (specifically, to sort the `color` variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166857/5783745) so it matches the order of another variable `sep_mean`). In uses like this the `match` approach works best because it will not allow extreme values to be displayed with less extreme colors in plots that happen to have a lot of the same value. Thanks for the answer and discussion, I will certainly keep both methods up my sleeve depending on the use case